# Stories For Boys Anthology

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

I am looking to identify an anthology. It was a 'Stories for Boys" type book of the kind common for my generation. It would have been published between 1930 and 1960.

The main reason for my needing identification was a story in there about a spacecraft encountering a living space serpent made of electricity that I would like to read again.

In it were also a story about a British explorer fighting a 'savage' monk of some kind and a boy who stopped a train disaster by holding a burning cloth.

The illustrations were also very good for the time. Hand drawn black and white.

Comment: Just to be clear, the anthology itself was not all SF, it was a general anthology with some SF stories?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Do you remember if it was a library book, or maybe an SBS book ordered through your school? Hardback?  Paperback?

Comment: It was not a library book. It was a hardback with a plain blue cover. There may have once been a paper cover of the kind that fits over hardbacks but I never saw it.

Comment: The story of the boy waving a burning cloth strikes a memory .... Maybe 1965 I had an anthology for Christmas and I think (but not 100%) that story was in it...the sci fi tales I don't recall at all. It was possibly titled 'Dean's adventure book for boys'

Comment: @DannyMcG are you thinking of Dean's Super Book For Boys?

Comment: I have been looking up the Deans Adventure Book angle. The physical form of the book does not resemble any of the photos I have seen on-line, for example https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/04gAAOSww5hZKp7C/s-l1600.jpg  - the book I remember had no colour at all. Cloth bound or plain board. However it does seem to be that kind of book.